# Grouping in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries (which I uploaded using a CSV), and I would like to run a "group by" equivalent based on one of the "columns".  I am trying to group on teamID and sum the "R" columns based on those groupings.

I am trying the following code:

```
import itertools

for key, group in itertools.groupby(batting, lambda item: item["teamID"]):
    print key, sum([item["R"] for item in group])
```

However, I am not seeing them grouped correctly.  There will be multiple instances of the same team ID.

For example:

```
RC1 30
CL1 28
WS3 28
RC1 29
FW1 9
RC1 0
BS1 66
FW1 1
BS1 13
CL1 18
```

Comment: groupby needs ordered data, use a defaultdict. You can sort the data by the  team id but why add n log n complexity when you can just as easily have a linear solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Padric said in his comment, `itertools.groupby()` needs ordered data to do what you want. The simplest solution (as in least code edits) would be:

```
import itertools

key_func = lambda item: item["teamID"]

for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(batting, key=key_func), key_func):
    print key, sum([item["R"] for item in group])
```

If your data is relatively big, you may want to consider something more efficient that doesn't require a duplicate sorted copy in memory. `defaultdict` mentioned in the comment may be a good choice.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for item in batting:
  d[item['teamID']] += item.get('R', 0) or 0

for team, r_sum in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
  print team, r_sum
```

The code may need slight adjustments for Python 3.

Comment: Sure, I've added an example.

Comment: The issue here is that 'teamID' is a string.  When I'm running this I get the error: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Sounds like you have some lines without R. I've updated the code to support that.

Comment: I updated it to sort by the team. If you want to sort by number, change 0 to 1.